# Getting last 5 rows in Each Group in mysql without scan full table

Tags: mysql

I want to get last 2 rows from each group without scanning full table. I have tried and got the result but query working with full table scan

I have a table like below one

```
+--------+-------+-----+
| Person | Group | Age |
+--------+-------+-----+
| Bob    | 1     | 32  |
| Jill   | 1     | 34  |
| Shawn  | 1     | 42  |
| Jake   | 2     | 29  |
| Paul   | 2     | 36  |
| Laura  | 2     | 39  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

I getting the result be like

```
+--------+-------+-----+
| Person | Group | Age |
+--------+-------+-----+
| Shawn  | 1     | 42  |
| Jill   | 1     | 34  |
| Laura  | 2     | 39  |
| Paul   | 2     | 36  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

check the below query,It is working with full table scan. kindly give a suggestion to avoid full table scan

```
SELECT a.person, a.group, a.age FROM person AS a WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person AS b 
WHERE b.group = a.group AND b.age >= a.age) <= 2 
ORDER BY a.group ASC, a.age DESC
```

Comment: a co-related  subquery is the worst possible approach in MySQL for getting the results you are after  as co-related subqueries not always tends to optimize the best..  You should  research MySQL 8 `ROW_NUMBER()` or simulate it with MySQL user variables...  *"check the below query,It is working with full table scan. kindly give a suggestion to avoid full table scan"* We can't as we don't know indexes on the table (`SHOW CREATE TABLE person`)

Answer (score 0):

```
  CREATE TABLE people(
   person  varchar(200),
  groupid int,
  age  int 
  );
INSERT INTO people(person,groupid,age) values("Bob",1,32);
INSERT INTO people(person,groupid,age) values("Jill ",1,34);
INSERT INTO people(person,groupid,age) values("Shawn",1,42);
INSERT INTO people(person,groupid,age) values("Jake",2,29);
INSERT INTO people(person,groupid,age) values("Paul",2,36);
INSERT INTO people(person,groupid,age) values("Laura",2,39);
INSERT INTO people(person,groupid,age) values("Jake",3,39);

 -- some how able to count two rows.  If less than two rows, throw 1
 SELECT groupid, 
 CASE  WHEN  count(groupid)>=2  THEN 2
       WHEN  count(groupid) = 1 THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 END 
 as possiblerows
 from people 
 group by groupid;
```

```
+---------+--------------+
| groupid | possiblerows |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 |            2 |
|       2 |            2 |
|       3 |            1 |
+---------+--------------+
```

I know this is not a the full solution. But this might get you started that you can count the rows before extracting them.